# MVC 4 DateTime? on model removal on edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have model which as a nullable Date field. Everything works as expected except in the circumstance where I am editing the model and I want to remove the date. Then validation is triggered:

[image]

How do I allow removal while also keeping validation on a partially filled in date? Is worth mentioning that are using a custom EditorTemplate:

[image]

Here is the code for the editor template:

```
@model DateTime?

@{    
    var months = new[] {
        new { Value = "", Display="" },
        new { Value = "1", Display = "01-Jan" },
        new { Value = "2", Display = "02-Feb" },
        new { Value = "3", Display = "03-Mar" },
        new { Value = "4", Display = "04-Apr" },
        new { Value = "5", Display = "05-May" },
        new { Value = "6", Display = "06-Jun" },
        new { Value = "7", Display = "07-Jul" },
        new { Value = "8", Display = "08-Aug" },
        new { Value = "9", Display = "09-Sep" },
        new { Value = "10", Display = "10-Oct" },
        new { Value = "11", Display = "11-Nov" },
        new { Value = "12", Display = "12-Dec" }
    };
    var monthSelect = new SelectList(months, "Value", "Display", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Month.ToString() : "");

    var days = new List<String>();
    days.Add("");
    days.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(s => s.ToString()));

    var daySelect = new SelectList(days.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x, x)), "Key", "Value", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Day.ToString() : "");
}


@Html.DropDownList("Month", monthSelect)
@Html.DropDownList("Day", daySelect)
@Html.TextBox("Year", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("yyyy") : string.Empty), new { style="width:75px;" })
```

The code on the edit view is dead simple:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDate)
```

Comment: allow it null in your model

Comment: Can you post your model's code?

Comment: Date is nullable. I'm using Entity Framework generating the models from the database.

Comment: Generally, you should put only the values that the UI needs into the ViewModel. So in this case, you would have a property for Month, a property for Day, and a property for Year instead of a whole DateTime.

Comment: Can you paste code of your UI ?